# tox throws "tox: error: unrecognized arguments:" for a seemingly valid command

Tags: python, testing, tox

**COMMAND:**

```
tox -e generated_p27, generated_p35 -- -v -n 5 --dist=loadfile
--vcr-record-mode=once
```

**OUTPUT**

> usage: tox [--version] [-h] [--help-ini] [-v] [--showconfig] [-l]
>   [-a]
>               [-c CONFIGFILE] [-e envlist] [--notest] [--sdistonly]
>               [--installpkg PATH] [--develop] [-i URL] [--pre] [-r]
>               [--result-json PATH] [--hashseed SEED] [--force-dep REQ]
>               [--sitepackages] [--alwayscopy] [--skip-missing-interpreters]
>               [--workdir PATH]
>               [args [args ...]]
>   tox: error: unrecognized arguments: -- -v -n 5 --dist=loadfile --vcr-record-mode=once

Why is tox throwing an error for a seemingly valid command?

Comment: Is the  `--` supposed to be positioned before or after the arguments?

Comment: its supposed to be positioned after the envlist and before the arguments needed to be passed to the command in `command=` section in tox.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option `-e` accepts one list of environments so remove space:

```
tox -e generated_p27, generated_p35
                    ^^^ here
```